# How to force the order of execution of two processes?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, deadlock

I have a parent process which spawns a certain number of child processes. Those child processes do some work and send the parent a message with the results via a interprocess message queue. However, I would also like the child processes to wait for the parent process to send them an acknowledgement that the message has been properly received and processed, and  terminate only after receiving such a signal from the parent.

Right now, the code looks more or less like this :

```
parent                      child
spawn process
wait for message            do processing
                            send message
receive message             wait on condvar
save the message
notify the condvar          resume execution
wait for child termination  terminate
```

Which, of course, leads to a deadlock if the parent does the `notify` on the condvar before the child even begins to wait on it - if that happens, then the parent waits for the child to exit, and the child waits for a signal on the condition variable.

So, my question is : how to ensure that the child always executes `wait` in the first place, that is before the parent executes `notify`? Or am I going about the whole problem completely wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use some inter-process object that remembers being signalled? What OS are you working on?

Comment: Windows. I'd rather use Boost if it offers a facility like this, though.

Comment: So, C++ then? Might be worth adding a tag for that and/or Boost.

Comment: Yep, C++. Forgot to add the tag. :)

Comment: Actually it does not matter which language (except in saying in which language to write code samples in answer). The problem is in how condvars are used and any language that has something called "condvar" uses it the same way.

Comment: Yup +  for @Damien_The_Unbeliever - I'd just use a named event or semaphore for this.  Boost seems to be somewhat lacking in basic synchro primitives :(

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: What boost has is what C++11 has and what you can count on having on all platforms. The set of synchronization primitives you have on Windows is somewhat unusual, so if you get used to it, you will have really big problem when you try to do something portable. Especially events are convenient for things like this, but than turn out seriously lacking when you actually need the full power of condvars.

Comment: @JanHudec Semaphores/Events are unusual?  <g>

Comment: @MartinJames: Events definitely. They are Windows-specific. Semaphores exist everywhere and are fine for this case, but only the in-process ones now have standard API. The inter-process named ones still don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an inter-process named semaphore or event - something that holds state, so that even if the parent signals before the child is waiting, the signal will still be received.

Comment: I ended up using an interprocess named semaphore, as I believe this is much more appropriate in this situation, an object that holds state. Thanks!

Comment: Please, don't even mention events. They are Windows-specific cut-down version of condition variables that don't exist anywhere else (on the other hand Windows struggle with implementing full condvars). Semaphores, on the other hand, exist everywhere and are usable for "completion" just fine.

Comment: Events, in one form or another, exist on several embedded multitaskers.  TBH, I don't use them much either, though they are occasionally useful, eg. when a thread needs to be temporarily paused.  Maybe Windows struggles to implement condvars because it doesn't want to support spurious wakeups? <g>

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are approaching the problem in wrong way. Or rather, using condvars the way they are not supposed to work. Condvar is a mean to notify the other thread that "something", a *condition*, has changed. It's that condition that allows the thread to terminate.

You need three elements to use condvar: *condition*, *mutex* and the *condvar* itself. Than the notifying thread will do:

```
{
    unique_lock(mutex);
    condition = true;
    condvar.notify();
}
```

and waiting thread will do:

```
{
    unique_lock(mutex);
    while(!condition)
        condvar.wait(mutex);
}
```

(using RAII for locking the mutex so I don't spread perception that calling `.lock()` and `.unlock()` methods directly is ever a good idea)

And note, that the `while` is *important*. `wait` may wake up spuriously even when not notified!